# Intellij Java Warning "Times" and "Lucida Bright" fonts are not available

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm using Java version 8 update 301 on intelliJ IDEA CE on Mac OS Big Sur and get the error:

> Warning: the fonts "Times" and "Lucida Bright" are not available for the Java logical font "Serif", which may have unexpected appearance or behavior. Re-enable the "Times" font to remove this warning.

Any idea how to re-enable the times font?

Comment: Hmm alright is there anyway to just disable them?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing these fonts using Font Book? You can find the Times font here: https://www.freebestfonts.com/timr45w-font But the Lucida font I couldn't find.

Comment: FYI… The [*Removal of Lucida Fonts from Oracle JDK*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8191522) section of the *JDK 11 Release Notes*  says: "Oracle JDK no longer ships any fonts and relies entirely on fonts installed on the operating system.

This means that fonts in the Bigelow & Holmes Lucida family (Lucida Sans, Lucida Bright, and Lucida Typewriter) are no longer available to applications from the JDK."

Answer (score 5):

The "Times" font is not available in macOS 12 Monterey. You can find it online and install it.

Or better, update Java to a more recent version; this change in macOS has been taken into account in Java, see [JDK-8273358](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8273358).

Answer (score 3):

You must do the following

1. Download the font from the [website](http://legionfonts.com/fonts/times)
2. Unzip the package font and install it
   [Install font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WUvl.png)
3. Restart the java application.

Answer (score 1):

Please download and install the fonts as below shown:

- Times https://www.freebestfonts.com/timr45w-font
- Lucida Bright https://www.wfonts.com/font/lucida-bright